# Assigning a pointer to a temporary object -- how to prevent it?

Tags: c++, pointers, temporary-objects

My class has a method with the following prototype:

```
std::string
Block::get_field(std::string rec_type, std::string field) { ... }
```

It retrieves a value from a map, converts it to a string, and returns the string.

Someone used my class as follows:

```
char * buf = block.get_field(my_rec, my_field).c_str();
```

Unless I'm mistaken, this is setting buf to point into a temporary string.  Not very much later, when he looked at *buf, it was corrupted.

Obviously I'd prefer my users write:

```
std::string buf = block.get_field(my_rec, my_field);
```

How do I, the author of Block, prevent abuses like this?  Or is there a way I can somehow support this usage?

**UPDATE 1:** This bug did not come to light until I changed the implementation of the map, from holding values directly, to holding "memory references" - a length and a pointer into a buffer.  But `get_field` has always returned a string -- not a `string*` or a `string&` -- so I would assume that it always returned a temporary.  I don't understand why it didn't break before (I'm also embarrassed; I claimed my changes would not affect the API).

I'm prepared to inform the user that he has to revise his code, but I'd like to be able to cite "The Rule" that he broke, and possibly explain how he happened to "luck out" before now.

**UPDATE 2:** It seems possible (in ref. to Update 1), that the reason the bug just now appeared is that my "under the hood" changes required me to add the following switch to g++ 4.4.7: **-std=gnu++0x**, which may have influenced the way in which temporaries are recycled.

Comment: Document it and be on your way. `std::stringstream` has the same problem.

Comment: That’s a straight-up bug (on the part of your user).

Comment: Mmm, return something that implicitly converts to a std::string and disallow .c_str() on the type?

Comment: No need to document this. I think it's fair to assume on your part that your users will know C++. Otherwise you'd need to add a full language tutorial in a comment before every function.

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth That's way more trouble than it's worth, and that even assuming it's worth preventing this mistake (see other comments). It forces one to introduce a variable or cast when you want to do anything to the temporary - whic is unnecessary when you could just do it on the temporary safely.

Comment: [This](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/13738820#13738820) is worth mentioning (but don't take it seriously of course).

Comment: @KerrekSB, I could go either way. This and the string stream one would be nice to have a reminder on I guess. Not something to specifically learn from, but a helpful bug-reducing reminder.

Comment: @Kerrek: No, assumptions are pathetic. They may be reasonable, but this is not a reasonable world, and documentation costs you very little. Have a heart.

Comment: @Jefffrey in that case, I'd quote this first: ["@Jefffrey So what? Whatever is returned, you can ***always*** still use `operator&` or `std::address_of(...)`"](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/13738803#13738803)

Comment: The fact that it's your library or another is irrelevant here. This user is bound to do things like `(a + "x").c_str()` anyway.

Comment: @delnan yeah, maybe, but it *will* take some extra aiming-for-foot this way, won't it :)

Comment: The problem isn't with your object.  The problem is with the user.  Your method creates a `std::string` object and returns it.  Your user uses the method `c_str()` from that object, and then that object goes out of scope (and presumably gets reclaimed and possibly reused).  When your user then attempts to dereference that `char*`, the results will be undefined.

Comment: @KerrekSB: What, specifically, is the C++ rule that the user violated?

Comment: @Chap: So far, none. But you have a dangling pointer, and it's an error to dereference that later on. When you write C++, you need to know where your pointers come from, and how to look this information up when using external interfaces. In other words, the documentation of `string` along with knowing lifetimes of temporaries explains what's going on. If anything, it's the documentation of `string::c_str()` that should say "Only valid while the object is alive"; but since that's in the standard library, it should be part of the user's training.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mostly you have to assume that users of your code are competent.

But this is a political world. So maybe sometimes you may have to do a probabilistic best effort to prevent mishaps. E.g.,

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <string>

class StdString: public std::string
{
private:
    using std::string::c_str;
    using std::string::data;
public:
    StdString( char const* const s ): std::string( s ) { assert( s != nullptr ); }
};

StdString foo() { return "Bah!"; }

int main()
{
    std::string const   a = foo();
    char const* const   b = foo().c_str();      //! Nyet.
}
```

Maybe throw in a move constructor there for good measure, but generally perfect efficiency is in conflict with perfect safety and perfect clarity, e.g. can has 2 but not 3.

Comment: On the other hand, `char const* const b = a.c_str();` would be safe, would it not?

Comment: That assert can never fire, though, can it? The `string` constructor will already throw when it gets a null pointer, or at least it's UB at that point.

Comment: @KerrekSB: the "it's UB" is the right possibility, the "will already throw" is the wrong one: throw or fail is not guaranteed, which is the reason for the `assert`.

Answer (score 2):

You really shouldn't have to prevent it, but if you see that happening a lot, you can change the prototype to:

```
void
Block::get_field(std::string& ret, std::string rec_type, std::string field) { ... }
```

Taking a reference: `std::string& ret` will force a std::string to exist before calling your method, while they can still do things to corrupt their memory it will happen in "their code". Something as simple as this bad code is very hard to prevent:

```
char * foo()
{
    std::string buffStr;
    block.get_field(bufStr, my_rec, my_field)
    return buffStr.c_str();         // DO NOT DO THIS - Example of bad code
}
```

But at least a mem checker will find their allocation and not yours

**UPDATE 1:**
The lifetime of the memory that `c_str()` returns is the lifetime of the `string` that generated it, unless the `string` is changed, in which case the lifetime may end then.   Basically, it is undefined behavior and may work sometimes, and not others.  Your changes may have changed the observed behavior, but at no time was the user code conformant.   Other factors could have broken it as well.  Basically, it was always broken, from your description there seems no reason to apologize.

Comment: So, it sounds like the crux of his error was using c_str() without understanding its pitfalls.  Stroustrup talks about the importance of maintaining "the invariant" of an object, whereas c_str() allows you to slip right past the interface and into the implementation.  I'd guess, then, that the c_str() should be frowned upon.

Comment: @Chap it's not c_str() per se, although there are many pitfalls it uncovers, the problem is that `string` "owns" the memory, so you have to keep it around.  As long as you can guarentee that the `string` is around, using c_str() is basically safe.  The problem as you found out, is that it's not always the case. (people have also been known to call strtok on the return from c_str())